# ¿Cómo convertir modelos 3D a css?

Tags: css, html5, css3, 3d, importación

Viendo css en 3D en http://tridiv.com/ me surgió la duda de si es posible importar modelos ya hechos en algun editor 3D como Blender o Maya para usarlos en alguna página hecha con css3 y HTML5.
Las búsquedas en google me arrojan demasiados resultados irrelevantes.

¿Alguien sabe como lograrlo?

Comment: interesante lo que se puede lograr con .CSS =0!

Comment: Existe un addon para blender, sobre Maya hace muchos años que no lo uso creo que mucho antes de que lo comprara Autodesk. con este addon tienes varias forma:

Metodo 1: Embed HTML
Metodo 2: Web Player
Metodo 1: Web App
https://www.blend4web.com/en/article/59/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probablemente [dom3d](http://jlongster.com/s/dom3d/) te sea de interes, posee un Scheme script que es capaz de transformar un archivo 3D de extension .obj a un mesh Javascript que dom3d es capaz de cargar.

Simplificandolo (quizás demasiado) exportas el modelo en .obj desde Blender o Maya, lo transformas con el script y lo cargas utilizando dom3d.

Viendo github, las ultimas actualizaciones son del 2011, pero quizás puedas utilizar el script de importacion de .obj con otro metodo.

Comment: Existe algo así? Genial.

Answer (score 6):

Ya te comentaron cómo puedes convertir un modelo sencillo a HTML y CSS con [dom3d](http://jlongster.com/s/dom3d/), pero si lo que quieres es un modelo más complejo con texturas, tendrías que usar WebGL.

Para eso puedes exportar un .obj desde varios programas y luego convertirlo a JSON para poder mostrarlo con [three.js](http://threejs.org/), Opera tiene una [guía](https://dev.opera.com/articles/introduction-to-webgl-part-2-porting-3d/) para hacer eso.

Otra alternativa es [x3dom](http://www.x3dom.org/), por último podrías usar visores comerciales para esto, como [Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/), [p3d](https://p3d.in/) o [Verold](https://www.verold.com), los cuales ya solo tienes agregar el modelo y hacer los ajustes conforme a ellos lo necesiten.

También si necesitas algo de interactividad podrías checar el webplayer de [Unity](https://unity3d.com/es/webplayer) o el *HTML5 Pipeline* de [Unreal Engine](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/HTML5/GettingStarted/).

Comment: he visto a muchos usar three.js, y los resultados son muy buenos